# Save MySQL query to a text file from shell

Tags: mysql, shell

I came across what I thought was a relatively simple problem, but haven't been able to find a solution. I wrote an extremely complex query in the MySQL shell and I'd like to save the query to a text file to use later and across systems (to use across redundant copies of the DB, and I unfortunately cannot copy paste).

Is there a simple way to do this, or will I have to manually retype the query into a text file?

Comment: Why can't you just copy/paste the sql text to a file like notepad? which shell you are using BTW? every shell has copy/paste feature.

Comment: Select. Copy. Paste.

Comment: I am using ubuntu server on a different macine than I'm on now. I'm logged into the mysql shell using `mysql -u root -p`

Comment: That's no issue. Which OS you are on (client machine)?

Comment: @Rahul I have a screen plugged into the server. So the host machine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typing `\e` will open your default `$EDITOR` (usually vi or vim) with the last query you ran. You can then type `:` to input commands and save the file using `w /path/to/myfile.sql`.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for

Comment: You can also use a client on your mac or pc. they can connect via ssh tunnel if the database not direct reach. So its easyer to work. But the answer from Mureinik is also OK

Comment: @BerndBuffen I know you can, but I wanted a way to save it on the shell specifically